# Django (wsgi) and Wordpress coexisting in Apache virtualhost

Tags: django, wordpress, mod-wsgi, apache-config

I have a Django project that I need mounted at two different subdirectories of my url, and I need Wordpress running at /. So:

```
*.example.com - WordPress
*.example.com/studio - django
*.example.com/accounts - django
```

Here's the httpd.conf that I have so far:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wildcard.localhost
    ServerAlias *.localhost

    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php
    DocumentRoot /var/empty

    Alias /site_media/ /home/zach/projects/python/myproject/static/
    Alias /media/ /home/zach/projects/python/myproject/env/lib/python2.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/media/
    Alias / /home/zach/projects/python/myproject/wordpress/

    WSGIScriptAlias /accounts /home/zach/projects/python/myproject/app/privio.wsgi
    WSGIScriptAlias /studio /home/zach/projects/python/myproject/app/privio.wsgi

    <Directory /home/zach/projects/python/myproject/app>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>

    <Directory /home/zach/projects/python/myproject/wordpress>
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    </Directory>
```

Before I added the config for WordPress, the Django app was working fine. But with this new setup I am able to see the WordPress install at /, but the Django app isn't getting served. I'm sort of a noob at Apache config - what am I missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Replace:

```
DocumentRoot /var/empty
```

with:

```
DocumentRoot /home/zach/projects/python/myproject/wordpress
```

Remove:

```
Alias / /home/zach/projects/python/myproject/wordpress/
```

Replace:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /accounts /home/zach/projects/python/myproject/app/privio.wsgi
WSGIScriptAlias /studio /home/zach/projects/python/myproject/app/privio.wsgi
```

with:

```
WSGIScriptAliasMatch ^(/(accounts|studio)) /home/zach/projects/python/myproject/app/privio.wsgi$1
```

In other words, use DocumentRoot to refer to wordpress that needs to be at root of site and not Alias directive.

The WSGIScriptAliasMatch is so Django itself thinks it is still mounted at root site even though only nominated sub URLs of it are actually passed through. This simplifies things for urls.py.

Note that the $1 at end of WSGI script path is important, so don't leave it off.

Answer (score 1):

Paging [Graham Dumpleton](https://stackoverflow.com/users/128141/graham-dumpleton) :)

I'd venture a guess that the line

```
Alias / /home/zach/projects/python/myproject/wordpress/
```

*overrides* everything below it. Therefore any requests to `/accounts` will be processed by the wordpress application rather than by the Django application.

From the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/QuickConfigurationGuide#Mounting_At_Root_Of_Site):

> **Mounting At Root Of Site**
>
> If instead you want to mount a WSGI application at the root of a site, simply list '/' as the mount point when configuring the WSGIScriptAlias directive.
>
> `WSGIScriptAlias / /usr/local/www/wsgi-scripts/myapp.wsgi`
>
> Do note however that doing so will mean that any static files contained in the DocumentRoot will be hidden and requests against URLs pertaining to the static files will instead be processed by the WSGI application.

Comment: That doesn't work with virtualhosts. Apache refuses: `Syntax error on line 3 of /path/to/project/vhost.conf:
WSGIPythonPath cannot occur within <VirtualHost> section`.