# How to setup up Django and wordpress together in root domain, Apache

Tags: php, django, apache, lamp

I have found the closest solution to my problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3534678/django-wsgi-and-wordpress-coexisting-in-apache-virtualhost) but still does not solve it entirely.

What we want to setup

1. example.com -     wordpress
2. example.com/about  wordpress
   There are about 4 more links
3. example.com/shortURLS  -Django

Since the URLs are so dynamic its kind of difficult to setup our environment.
Would be really great if anyone can advice how to set it up for Apache.

Comment: Two options:

1. Use a proxy - like nginx - to map URLs.
2. Set all URLs to point to django, then forward/redirect them from there.