# Kill the background process executed by python

Tags: python, django, pid

I have a script

```
import os
os.system('python manage.py runserver')
```

The script starts django server (no matter what it does, it can be any command which evaluates until `ctrl+c` or another key shortcut is pressed).

What I want is to stop the server by any way but not by killing it by pid.

---

What I've tried:

I tried to use `subprocess` lib and it's `kill` command as described here: [How to terminate a python subprocess launched with shell=True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4789837/how-to-terminate-a-python-subprocess-launched-with-shell-true)

But it does not help. As I guess, the reason is: we are killing not the `manage.py runserver` process but the process which evaluates `python manage.py runserver`. So, after killing process, server is still running.

Also I've tried use `terminate` method:

```
p = subprocess.Popen('python manage.py runserver', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
time.sleep(5)
p.terminate()
```

As I think it should work this way: server starts and after 5 seconds it stops, but it never stops.

Is there any way to kill the process?

Comment: have you created a new process group as the answer from the question you've linked recommends? `runserver` doesn't demonize the server process therefore the recipe should work.

Comment: don't use `stdout=PIPE` if you don't read from the pipe. Use [DEVNULL instead  if you want to discard the output](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11269575/4279)

Comment: Thank you so much! I've just tried again the answer from the question i've linked and... everything works. I don't know why it didn't work for the first time, but now it does exactly what I want. So thank you for pointing me again to that question and additional thank you for DENVULL (the undesirable output was my second problem)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This sounds dubious.** Please don't do that!

Django recommends using WSGI to allow the webserver (Apache, NginX, etc) to load and unload Django as necessary automatically. [Here's how to do that](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/deployment/wsgi/). Also, Django's built-in web server isn't considered [secure or scalable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867793/using-djangos-built-in-web-server-in-a-production-environment). In general, don't do that!

If you're averse to using WSGI, you can also do a [proxypass with Apache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12631041/proxypass-and-proxypassreverse-for-django-app), [NginX](https://lincolnloop.com/django-best-practices/deployment/servers.html), etc. The Django server itself can be managed by any number of system service tools, like [init.d](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/boot.html) or [supervisord](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/HighQuality-Apps-HOWTO/boot.html).

To directly answer to your question, you could use `process.terminate()` to kill the active process launched with `subprocess`, but it's a terrible idea to run your server by yourself with a python script when so many other great tools exist.

Comment: the thing is: for the development I want one command to start local webserver, coffee & less compilers. And one command to kill them all simultaneously

Comment: `terminate` command does not work, updated my question to show what I do with terminate